# Where can I watch The Seven Deadly Sins?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I have seen the first 10 episodes of *The Seven Deadly Sins*, but now I cannot find the rest.

Where else can I watch it?

Comment: Are they not still on Netflix?

Comment: I no longer have Netflix, but when I had it only the first 10 episodes were available.

Comment: @Mauricio actually, Netflix now has 3 seasons, and a movie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this Crunchyroll Forum Thread](https://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-1020745/seven-deadly-sins-anime-is-not-here) Netflix has the exclusive streaming rights.

on the [Australian Netflix site](https://www.netflix.com/au/title/80050063) it lists:

- 24 episodes for Season 1 (2014)
- 4 episodes for Signs of Holy War (2016)
- 24 episodes for  Revival of the Commandments (2018)

Comment: Not sure about other countries, but Netflix in the USA also has a SDS movie, too